# The usage of select_array() in Query builder

Tags: mysql, query-builder

**The usage of the select_array():**

```
$value = array( 'username', 'email', 'firstname' );

$result = DB::select_array( $value ) ->from( 'user' ) ->where( 'userid', '=', '1' ) ->execute() ->as_array();

print_r( $result[0] );
```

Comment: Nice. Now, could you ask your question?

Comment: How can use alias in select_array()?

Comment: if you want to ask like __The usage of select_array() in Query builder?__ then it means the name of fields that you want fetch from the query, and it is good practice to fetch the necessary field instead of all the fields.

Comment: Thanks. but i need all fields with other name. And the query value will passing in the controller itself. I need some suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this might be it helps you.

```
$value = array( 
              array('username', 'uname'), 
              array('email', 'mail'), 
              array('firstname', 'fname') 
         );

DB::select_array( $value ) 
        ->from( 'user' ) 
        ->where( 'userid', '=', '1' ) 
        ->execute() 
        ->as_array();
```

take a look on [select_array](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/database/qb_select.html#method_select_array)

Comment: and we can try this one also. $value = array( 
              'username' =>array('username', 'uname'), 
              'email' => array('email', 'mail'), 
              'firstname' => array('firstname', 'fname') 
         );